# Создание изображения из чисел

Tags: c#, массивы, visual-studio

Всем привет

Требуется помощь в одном задании

Есть набор чисел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

0 - это не закрашенный пиксель, 1 - закрашенный.

Вместо того, чтобы получилось вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня получилось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? Считывание идёт построчно.
Вот код (проект тоже прикрепляю с файлом):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ImageArrayWF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    private string str = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int stolb = 64, strok = 128;
        int[,] array2D = new int[stolb, strok];

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"Disp.txt");
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            str += streamReader.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);

        Graphics dc = this.CreateGraphics();
        Brush[] brushes = {new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
            new SolidBrush(Color.White) };
        for (int i = 0; i < stolb; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < strok; j++)
            {
                array2D[i, j] = (int) char.GetNumericValue(str[i * strok + j]);
                dc.FillRectangle(brushes[array2D[i, j]], j * 10, i * 10, 10, 10);
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

[Проект](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J_4DFcSFRP0MHpCkASYodUWIUNUno4pG)

Comment: Сколько строк на один столбец?

Comment: Всего 1024 строчек

Comment: Вы не поняли, ширина и высота дисплея какая?

Comment: Аа. Теперь понял. Ширина и высота: 128х64

Comment: Будут у Вас какие-то идеи? Извините :(

Comment: Лмбо файл неверный, либо вы неверно его формат разбираете. Я не смотрел на ваш код, разобрал файл как вы написали в тексте вопроса, получил [точно такую же картинку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNmdK.png).

Comment: Знать бы порядок отрисовки... Было бы проще, а так я уже устал играться с циклами.

Comment: Хм, почти, но [не совсем](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymZGO.png)... Хоть и перевернутую но букву `M` уже видно.

Comment: Файл номер 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaUHs.png, исходя из этого, мне кажется что расположение точек, распологается зеркально, т.е. с обратной стороны.

Comment: Откуда Вы вообще эти файлы взяли?

Comment: Устройство дисплея генерирует

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже было сказано, в файле картинка хранится блоками размером 128 строк * 8 столбцов (то есть вся картинка - это 8 длинных полос друг под другом). Каждая строка в это блоке перевернута по горизонтали. Плюс само изображение повернуто на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки.

Что я сделал:

1. Считываем все строки, каждую строку переворачиваем
2. Считанные строки разбиваем на блоки для отрисовки
3. Каждый блок отрисовываем, переворачивая и отражая всё изображение.

Для отрисовки одной точки я написал такую функцию

```
    private static void Draw(char s, int x, int y)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(s);
    }
```

Далее, определил константы для всего изображения и блока

```
    const int rows = 64, columns = 128;
    const int blockRows = 128, blockColumns = 8;
```

После считываем блоки

```
    private static IEnumerable<bool[]> ReadFile(string file)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(l => l.Reverse().ToArray()).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            var block = new bool[blockRows * blockColumns];

            for (var r = 0; r < 128; r++)
            {
                for (var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
                {
                    var ch = lines[i * 128 + r][c];
                    if (ch == '1') block[r * 8 + c] = true;
                }
            }

            yield return block;
        }
    }
```

Ну и основная функция с отрисовкой

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WindowWidth = columns;
        Console.WindowHeight = rows;

        var offsetRows = 0;

        foreach (var block in ReadFile(@"D:\temp\Disp.txt"))
        {

            for (var r = 0; r < 128; r++)
            {
                for (var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
                {
                    if (block[r * 8 + c])
                    {
                        Draw('▓', blockRows - r, offsetRows + c);
                    }
                }
            }

            offsetRows += blockColumns;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Адаптированная под `WinForms` версия от **@tym32167**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Rectangle[] _drawableRectangles;

    const int rows = 64, columns = 128;
    const int blockRows = 128, blockColumns = 8;
    const int scaleFactor = 10;
    const int margin = scaleFactor / 2;

    private static IEnumerable<bool[]> ReadFile(string file)
    {
        char[][] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(l => l.Reverse().ToArray()).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < blockColumns; i++)
        {
            bool[] block = new bool[blockRows * blockColumns];

            for (int r = 0; r < blockRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < blockColumns; c++)
                {
                    char ch = lines[i * blockRows + r][c];
                    if (ch == '1') block[r * blockColumns + c] = true;
                }
            }

            yield return block;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClientSize = new Size(columns * scaleFactor + margin, rows * scaleFactor + margin);

        int offsetRows = 0;

        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

        foreach (bool[] block in ReadFile(@"Disp.txt"))
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < blockRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < blockColumns; c++)
                {
                    if (block[r * blockColumns + c])
                    {
                        points.Add(new Point(margin + (blockRows - r) * scaleFactor, margin + (offsetRows + c) * scaleFactor));
                    }
                }
            }

            offsetRows += blockColumns;
        }

        _drawableRectangles = (from Point p in points select new Rectangle(p, new Size(scaleFactor / 2, scaleFactor / 2))).ToArray();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.White, _drawableRectangles);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Офигеть как круто. Я столько проигрался с этим и вот наконец-то. Спасибо вам парни большое. Вы лучшие. Что бы я делал без вас - не знаю. Как мне вас отблагодарить?

Comment: @razorqhex ничего не надо, плюсика и галочки достаточно :)

Comment: Скажите, а насколько это верный алгоритм? Просто мне сбросили другие данные и там картинка чуть-чуть косячная. Хотел бы узнать: если-ли разница какой будет текстовый документ. Просто вдруг текстовый документ с этими данными верный. Извините, если что пожалуйста :(

Comment: @razorqhex вся картинка отрисована по вашему файлу. Потому если будет какой то другой файл - будет другая картинка

Comment: Это да. Посмотрите пожалуйста внизу поста. Я комментарий добавлю в виде ответа на свой пост. Извините за то, что надоедаю :(

Comment: @razorqhex не надо добавлять ответы, правьте вопрос, добавляйте всё, что нужно, в вопрос

Comment: Не увидел Ваш ответ пока писал :(

Comment: Всё заработало. Проблема была в том, что устройство сгенерировало не совсем верные данные. Большое Вам спасибо :)

Comment: @razorqhex пожалуйста )

Answer (score 2):

> Теоритический ответ

Исходя из того сколько я пробовал выполнить отрисовку по точкам, ничего успешного не вышло, за исключением искоженного второго файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но! Тут есть одно большое но, такого результат удалось достичь только после того, как я начал переворачивать массив считанной строки в обратную сторону, вот то что было до того как перевернул массив считанной строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если хорошо присмотреться, то изображение не только перевернуто, но оно еще и отражено в обратную сторону, т.е. зеркально.

Далее я приложу свой код которым удалось достич такого эффекта, думаю если будет время я его сам дораьотаю, но к сожалению пока его нет.

Простой незамысловатый код чтения блоками сверху вниз по 8 ячеек:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Rectangle[] _drawableRectangles;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClientSize = new Size(128 * 10, 64 * 10);

        bool[][][] _array3D;

        using (TextReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"Disp2.txt"))
        {
            _array3D = new bool[16][][];
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                _array3D[j] = new bool[64][];
                for (int k = 0; k < 64; k++)
                {
                    char[] buffer = new char[8];
                    streamReader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, 8);
                    Array.Reverse(buffer);
                    _array3D[j][k] = buffer.Select(c =>
                    {
                        return c == '1';
                    }).ToArray();
                    streamReader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, 2);
                }
            }
        }

        List<Point> tempPoints = new List<Point>();

        for (int x = 15; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            for (int y = 63; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if (_array3D[x][y][j])
                    {
                        tempPoints.Add(new Point(j * x * 5, y * 5));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        _drawableRectangles = tempPoints.Select(point => new Rectangle(point, new Size(5, 5))).ToArray();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.White, _drawableRectangles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Кстати, я думаю если читать блоки слева направо по 8х8 то изображение должно выйти корректным.

Comment: пишу ответ [про блоки 128*8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSBzo.png), можете поэкспериментировать :)

Comment: @tym32167: О как, это мой код помог?)

Comment: да, идея с блоками ваша :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь парни.Вы лучшие. Сколько сидел над этим заданием и вот наконец-то. Спасибо