# Вывести числа в виде LCD дисплея

Tags: c#

Задача заключается в том, чтобы вывести введенные числа в виде LCD - Дисплея.

Входные данные содержат несколько строк, по строке для каждого числа, которое нужно отобразить. Каждая строка содержит целые числа s и n, где n - это число, которое нужно отобразить (0 ≤ n ≤ 99 999 999) и s, это размер, в котором оно должно быть изображено (0 ≤ s ≤ 10). Входные данные заканчиваются строкой, состоящей из двух нулей, которую не нужно обрабатывать.

Выведите числа указанные во входных данных в стиле LCD-дисплея, используя s «-» символов для горизонтальных сегментов и s «|» символов для вертикальных. Каждая цифра занимает ровно s + 2 колонок и 2 s + 3 строк. Не забудьте заполнить все белое пространство, занимаемое цифрами, пробелами, включая последнюю цифру. Между двумя цифрами должна быть точно одна колонка пробелов. Выводите пустую строку после каждого числа.

Подскажите как можно реализовать данную программу? В голове крутятся идеи про двумерный массив.

Comment: Задача в стиле нарисуйте SVG но для c#?

Comment: `В голове крутятся идеи про двумерный массив.` В голове должна крутится идея иерархии классов для отображения цифр от 0 до 9. Ну или на худой конец нарисуйте заранее в текстовых файлах нужные цифры и добавьте в проект в виде ресурсов, а затем используйте их для отображения чисел.

Comment: @Bulson было бы все так просто, если бы там не было размеров цифр.

Comment: Взять шрифт, стилизованный под LCD.

Comment: `«-» символов для горизонтальных сегментов и s «|» символов для вертикальных` а для угловых, а для смежных, их вообще не надо отрисовывать?

Comment: @aepot нет, цифры должны быть квадратными, в плане, что везде где могут быть изгибы, под 90* углы

Comment: Об этом не написано в задании, почему вы так решили? `Не забудьте заполнить все белое пространство, занимаемое цифрами, пробелами, включая последнюю цифру.` в этом нет никакого смысла, если то что вы утверждаете про углы - правда.

Comment: Вопрос в другом, если число 8 знаков, а s = 10, то ширина числа будет 13 * 8 - 1 = 103 символа, что не влезает в стандартный буфер консоли, но это важно только для отображения. Для проверяющей задание программы этоине имеет значения. Еще вопрос. Если s = 0, то цифру не нарисовать, потому что ее ширина будет 2, а высота 3. Это скорее всего ошибка в задании, уточните этот вопрос у преподавателя или куратора.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980266/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb возможно чем нибудь поможет